# Design a Windows Service with self-hosted ASP.NET Core Web Services and UPD port listeners

Tags: object-oriented, web-services, sockets, asp.net-core

I'm designing a software platform in automation that is responsible of many different tasks like:

- Core functions
- Driver interface for machines
- UDP listener for machine messages from PLC
- UDP listener for other software components messages (other port)
- Internal control Web Service used by external components of platform, such as administration client
- Other things...

My idea is to create a **single Windows Service** that is developed in a modular way, so that there is more or less a module for each of the above listed functions, so that you can enable/disable each module independently, and at the same time, being able to start all the modules with the start of the service.

Now, my main doubts are 2:

1. Is it a valid architecture? Or is it preferable to separate the
   modules into individual services or components of some kind? In this
   case, how can I achieve to have the total management of all the
   modules?
2. If the architecture that I thought can be good, how can I implement
   the start up and management of the different modules within the
   Windows Service?

I have already read several articles explaining how to develop a Windows Service with **C#** and **VS 2017** (using **Topshelf** to make debugging easier) that hosts **one** self-hosted Web API Web Service or **one** .NET Core Web Service.
I think that could be the way for me and I'm very attracted to the idea of using **.NET Core** for API, **.NET Standard** for shared function libraries and a Windows Service.
But I don't know how to implement the scaffolding for a Windows Service that hosts **all those different components**.

Articles:

- [Creating Windows Service in .NET with Topshelf](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-windows-service-in-net-with-topshelf/)
- [Web API self-hosting using Windows Service](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b1df45/web-api-self-hosting-using-windows-service/)
- [Self-host ASP.NET Web API as a Windows Service](https://codeopinion.com/self-host-asp-net-web-api-as-a-windows-service/)
- [Creating .NET Core Windows Services](https://stackify.com/creating-net-core-windows-services/)
- [Publishing ASP.NET Core Windows Service](https://myview.rahulnivi.net/publishing-asp-net-core-windows-service/)